# Easy way to fix reports after changing lookup field to master-detail

Tags: reporting, lookup, dashboard, master-detail

Changing a lookup relationship to a master detail breaks all reports and dashboards that are dependent on that relationship. That is a somewhat undesirable result. I was wondering if there is an easy way to fix those reports without rebuilding them all?

(The business case for spending time on this is rather weak, so i'm really looking for something quick here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Eclipse or any IDE of your choice that can pull reports metadata:
To find out the differences - you would have to pull the existing reports before making changes, or use sandbox  to see the original reports metadata, then recreate at least one of the reports in Salesforce after the field conversion, and compare them to the original.
Metadata files are text/xml, so most of reports can be converted with search/replace.

Comment: Thank you for the response Oleksiy. Have you perhaps tried this solution? If so how much time did you spend on it?

Comment: Yes, we were migrating one app from using standard CRM objects to custom only objects, including data migration and all reports recreated to use these new custom objects instead. It all depend on how many reports you have that could potentially cause some issues - e.g. when you have formula fields, joined report type. Another problem is reports stored in user's Personal folders - admins can't access them, and we asked users to move their reports they want to have recreated into designated folders.
This could be as quick as in a few hours, and could take weeks in some cases

Comment: Thank you @Oleksiy! Good to know this is possible. I'll suggest it to my boss as a possible solution.